# How can i select the right row?

Tags: php, html

Page 1 :

```
<div>
<?php
        $reponse = $db->query('SELECT * FROM societe;');

?>

    <table border=1>
        <form method="post" action="ModifSociete.php">
    <?php
        $increm = 1;
        while($donne = $reponse->fetch()){
    ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $donne['NomSoc']; ?>" name="nomSoc<?php echo $increm; ?>"/>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $donne['ID']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo 'Societe '.$donne['NomSoc']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $donne['Lieu']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $donne['Mail']; ?></td>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $donne['ID']; ?>" name="getIdSoc<?php echo $increm; ?>"/>
                <td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Modifier"/></td>
            </tr>

    <?php
        $increm++;
        }
        $reponse->closeCursor(); 

    ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $increm; ?>" name="nbIncrem"/>
        </form>
    </table><br/>
</div>
```

Page 2 :

```
<form method="post" action="UpdateSociete.php">
<?php
//WHERE ID = "'.$_POST['getIdSoc'.$i.''].'"
    $getNomSoc = $db->query('SELECT * FROM societe;');

    $thisSociete =array();
    $i=0;
    while($data = $getNomSoc->fetch()){

        $thisSociete[$i]["NomSoc"] = $data['NomSoc'];
        $thisSociete[$i]["Lieu"] = $data['Lieu'];
        $thisSociete[$i]["Mail"] = $data['Mail'];
        $thisSociete[$i]["ID"] = $data['ID'];
        $i++;               
    }
    $j=1;

        $thisSocieteNom = "";
        $thisSocieteLieu = "";
        $thisSocieteMail = "";
        if($_POST['nomSoc'.$j.''] == $thisSociete[$j-1]["NomSoc"]){
            var_dump($_POST['nomSoc'.$j.'']);
            var_dump($thisSociete[$j-1]["NomSoc"]);

            $thisSocieteNom = $thisSociete[$j-1]["NomSoc"];
            $thisSocieteLieu = $thisSociete[$j-1]["Lieu"];
            $thisSocieteMail = $thisSociete[$j-1]["Mail"];
?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $thisSociete[$j-1]["ID"]; ?>" name="getIdSocBis"/>
<?php
        }
        else{
            $j++;
        }

?>
<input type="hidden" value="kangourou" name="passwordAdmin" />
<div>
    <h4>Modifier la societe <?php //get le nom de la soiete ?> :</h4>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Nom : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ajoutNomSoc" value="<?php echo $thisSocieteNom; ?>"></input></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Lieu : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ajoutLieu" value="<?php echo $thisSocieteLieu; ?>"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Mail : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ajoutMail" value="<?php echo $thisSocieteMail; ?>"></input></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer"/>
```

My page 2 is used to update the information in the table from the first pages.

My problem is that i dont know how to select the row i want to update.
With my code i always update the first but i dont know what i have to change to select the row i want.

What I want :
My table has 4 column. The last one is the submit button. When i click on one of them I go on my second pages (where i can see the information od the row in the text input) and i can change the information of my row (the one where i clicked on the submit button).

How can i do that ?

P.S. : I tried to be the clearest i could...

Comment: Use arrays on your html: `<input type="text" name="myNamesArray[]">`. You can insert inside the unique id to get better the record you need: `<input type="text" name="myNamesArray[<?= $id; ?>]">`

Comment: On which page ? (im started in php so i didnt understood everything sry)

Comment: either you have a separate page for each action, then `select all societies`  on the 4th column of you table, you have a link to `update.php?idsociety=$thisSocieteID` and then you catch `idsociety` and use it to update the record according to your society ID or do as @MarcosPérezGude says, you have many ways to achieve this

Comment: On the first page, build the form with the id on the array. On the second page you'll receive `$_POST['myNamesArray'][1];$_POST['myNamesArray'][25];....etc` where 1 and 25 are the ids of the element you are trying to edit.r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GET params to pass the ID from page 1 to page 2.

Change

```
<td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Modifier"/></td>
```

To

```
<td><a href="ModifSociete.php?id=<?php echo $donne['ID']; ?>">Modifier</a></td>
```

In page 2, try to select the item you parse through GET params $_GET['id']

```
$getNomSoc = $db->query('SELECT * FROM societe WHERE ID = "' . $_GET['id'] . '";');
```

Comment: Thats not a bad idea but then my form will have no submit :s is it possible ?

Comment: You can remove all the form and input in the first page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think here you need to send post request. what you need to do is:

```
    while($donne = $reponse->fetch()){
?>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $donne['NomSoc']; ?>" name="nomSoc<?php echo $increm; ?>"/>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $donne['ID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo 'Societe '.$donne['NomSoc']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $donne['Lieu']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $donne['Mail']; ?></td>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $donne['ID']; ?>" name="getIdSoc<?php echo $increm; ?>"/>
            <td><a href="ModifSociete.php?id=<?php echo $donne['ID']; ?>">Modifier</a> </td>
        </tr>
```

on second page you will get unique ID which will help you to select record based on it

Comment: Thanks body the same answer is already post just above you ^^